# code signing rejected during build leads to invalid certificate after notarization

Tags: macos, electron, electron-forge

Code signing fails with a simple rejected during packaging:

```
Packaging ApplicationWARNING: Code sign failed; please retry manually. Error: Command failed: spctl --assess --type execute --verbose --ignore-cache --no-cache /var/folders/kw/fp514mmd4djdrld7q8_ttp4r0000gr/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/myapp-darwin-x64/myapp.app
/var/folders/kw/fp514mmd4djdrld7q8_ttp4r0000gr/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/myapp-darwin-x64/myapp.app: rejected
```

After notarization, the app crashes with this error:

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes:       UNKNOWN_0x32 at 0x0000001e0000a5c0
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000032, 0x0000001e0000a5c0
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 2
```

These are my packaging options in electron.config.js:

```
        osxSign: {
            identity:
                'Developer ID Application: ### (###)',
        },
        osxNotarize: {
            appleId: '###',
            appleIdPassword: '###',
            teamId: '###',
            ascProvider: '###',
        },
```

The certificate is listed in Xcode, Keychain Access and in `security find-identity -p codesigning -v` without warnings and with the related private key attached. I specified it in my config after experiencing the same behavior with the default configuration.

Any ideas what else to try, or what causes the rejection?

Comment: we would need some details obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that New provisioning profiles / certificates require notarization to pass spctl checks. So `gatekeeperAssess` needs to be set to `false` for `spctl`. My version of `@electron/osx-sign` was outdated and did not take that into account. I had to update `@electron-forge/*` to `>=6.0.4`

Comment: If code sign fails how do you notarize?

Comment: good question. ask apple why they allow the upload of a unsigned .app to be notarized without throwing an error. anyway that is not relevant for the question since it was a bug caused by an outdated @electron/osx-sign version

Comment: Logically though a failure in codesign should error prior to notary.

Comment: And it did. But it was only treated as a warning. And notarization did not.